# disable boxZoom when control key active

Tags: leaflet

I am using the [area select](https://github.com/w8r/leaflet-area-select) plugin. By default it responds to a ctrlKey box drag. And by default Leaflet boxZoom responds to a shiftKey box drag. All good so far. However a ctrlKey + shiftKey box drag triggers the Leaflet boxZoom and the area select plugin. I would like it to trigger just the area select plugin instead. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at [Leaflet's source code for the `BoxZoom` map handler](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/525492bb537af87826102fc525949eb1679b68eb/src/map/handler/Map.BoxZoom.js#L62), you can see the line where it checks for a pressed shift key plus primary (""left"") mouse/pointer button to start the box zoom:

```
_onMouseDown: function (e) {
    if (!e.shiftKey || ((e.which !== 1) && (e.button !== 1))) { return false; }
```

And you want to change that to check for [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey), so that the box zoom doesn't start if it's set to `true`, something like:

```
    if (!e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || ((e.which !== 1) && (e.button !== 1))) { return false; }
```

The question is how to do this without rewriting or breaking up everything. An approach is to monkey-patch that method from the `BoxZoom` handler's `prototype` while keeping a reference to the old one, e.g. something like:

```
var oldBoxZoomMouseDown = L.Map.BoxZoom.prototype._onMouseDown;

L.Map.BoxZoom.prototype._onMouseDown = function(ev) {
    // Worry only about ctrlKey...
    if (ev.ctrlKey) { return false; }

    // ...and let the previous event handler worry about shift and primary button
    oldBoxZoomMouseDown.call(this, ev);
}
```

Note that it'll work only when done *before* the map has been instantiated. There are other approaches, such as replacing the method of the `BoxZoom` *instance* after the map has been instantiated, and creating a subclass of the `BoxZoom` handler. Reading about javascript's [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance) and [Leaflet's way of dealing with OOP](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html) is recommended at this point.

Comment: Nice. The reminder about modifying the prototype before instantiation and saving the original version are very helpful.